# How can I get delay from my Keypress event?

Tags: javascript

I need to make a delay for my keypress event because it only takes the second number that I press.

```
$('#cuota').on('keypress', function(event) {

            var precio_origen = $('#cuota).val();

            console.log(precio_origen);

        });
```

Comment: That's probably because, you're looking at the wrong event. Look at `input` or `keydown` events and also, keep the following in mind: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: "it only takes the second number" that's because keypress event is triggered for every single keypress. Assuming "#cuota" is an input element, use the "change" event

Answer (score 1):

The `keypress` event is fired when the input control's  value has not been updated yet. If you want to get an event when that value is already updated, use the `input` event.

```js
$("#cuota").on("input", function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Input: <input id="cuota">
```

Comment: Can you make an example?